# Not able to install Shellter - Crypter

Tags: kali-linux

I am not able to install Shellter Crypter in Kali Linux. I tried all the ways described by searching on google but no success.

Can anyone guide me for the same.

Comment: Have you tried the instruction [on the official website](https://www.shellterproject.com/download/)? `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install shellter`

Answer (score 0):

`shellter` is a `non-free` package, you should have the following line in your`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Use the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install shellter
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and update